# Flutter Web Http request strange response

Tags: http, flutter, dart, flutter-web

Hello i am trying to make a http request in flutter for web, but I am having a lot of problems here.
Response for any request I am doing looks like this:

[image: response]

I am making requests like this:

[image: httpget]

Ok, I realised that if i decode response like this:

```
var responseBody = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

I get:

[image]

Still I don't have full key-value response and the status code

How can I get normal respone?

Comment: unexpected error from chrome devtools

Comment: Ok I see that if i decode like this: json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
I am having a list, but only the key values of Response

Comment: {cache-control: no-cache, private, content-type: application/json}

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you you need to decode you response body with `json.decode` from `dart:convert`.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final response = await http.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = json.decode(response.body);
}
```